# Bash not recognising python command

Tags: python, bash

I have this command as part of a bash script

```
$(python -c "import urllib, sys; print urllib.unquote(sys.argv[0])", "h%23g")
```

But when I run it, I get this:

```
-bash: -c: command not found
```

As though bash has missed reading the `python`, and is thinking `-c` is the name of the command. Exactly the same happens when using backticks.

How can I make bash recognise the `python`?

Comment: put it inside backticks? (just a guess im on windows atm)

Comment: @Joran tried that, exactly the same result.

Comment: What is `python` aliased to?  It looks like it might be an empty string...or perhaps `echo`.  What happens if you write `$(\python ...)`?  Do you really want to execute the output of the Python script?

Comment: Is that last comma intentional and in the correct place?

Comment: @jpm the one here- argv[0])", "? Well, it's needed to pass `"h%23g"` into the python command isn't it?

Comment: @Jonathan `$ type --all python` gives `python is /usr/bin/python`

Comment: @ACarter Nope. Arguments are just space delimited:

`-c command
    Specify the command to execute (see next section). This terminates the option list (following options are passed as arguments to the command).`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want something like the following:

```
$(python -c "import urllib, sys; print urllib.unquote(sys.argv[1])" "h%23g")
```

This will result in `h#g`, if this is all you have on a line then it will also attempt to run a command called `h#g`, so I'm assuming you are actually using this as a part of a larger command.

The issue with your version is that `sys.argv[0]` is the `-c` from the command, and `urllib.unquote('-c')` will just return `'-c'`.

From the [documentation on `sys.argv`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.argv):

> If the command was executed using the `-c` command line option to the interpreter, `argv[0]` is set to the string `'-c'`.

Combining that with info from the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/python) (emphasis mine):

> **-c** *command*
>   Specify the command to execute (see next section). This terminates the option list **(following options are passed as arguments to the command)**.

So, when you use `-c`, `sys.argv[0]` will be `'-c'`, the argument provided to `-c` is the script so it will not be included in `sys.argv`, and any additional arguments are added to `sys.argv` starting at index 1.

Comment: Also, unless the python script is printing a command, this shouldn't be on its own line. Otherwise, it will try to interpret the result as a command. Either do the command w/o command substitution (so it just prints out) or use command substitution to assign the result to a variable.

Answer (score 6):

the Python command is returning the string "-c" from your $(...) structure, which bash then tries to execute.

for example

```
python -c "import urllib, sys; print urllib.unquote(sys.argv[0])"
```

prints "-c", so you are essentially asking bash to interpret $(-c), for which the error is valid.